# Any recommendations for a Pre-show music for The Producers?

Tags: sound-design, music

I am new to this forum, hell I'm new to sound design as a whole. I am currently working on a production of [The Producers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Producers_(musical)) and was asked to do the pre-show music and intermission music. I was thinking about doing old Broadway style music with some big band thrown in for good measure. Any other recommendations?

Thank you all in advance.
D.Brown

Comment: Hi D.Brown can you change your title to a question?

Comment: I can, however if I do the meaning of the question would be lost. It's a specific genre of music in it. Unless it is for legal reasons.

Comment: As it is, the question seems very broad to me. Are you expecting references to existing pieces of music or do you plan to compose some original music ?

Comment: Perhaps you would like to put this question in http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/, it seems to me more appropriate for that stack.